# Удалить определенные символы

Tags: php

Добрый вечер. Есть строка:

```
videoUpdate(2147383355,1363,1)
```

Как мне оставить от нее только **2147383355**, При условии, что все цифры и их количество меняется? Желательно через  preg_replace, но если это не очень хороший вариант то ладно.

Comment: Вам нужно первое число после открывающейся скобки?

Comment: Да. То, что жирным выделено.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть совсем простой вариант.

```
$s="videoUpdate(2147383355,1363,1)";
$n = sscanf($s, "videoUpdate(%d,%d,%d)", $num1, $num2, $num3);
print("num1=$num1");
```

Результат:

```
num1=2147383355
```

А как остальные числа, точно не нужны?

Comment: Ого, вы просто разбили строки на переменные. Действительно, простой вариант, спасибо. Да, остальные числа не нужны, а если понадобятся, то понятно как вывести.

Comment: @gm-111 Ну тогда можете галочку поставить :)

Comment: Забыл про галочку :)

Comment: По сути ведь та же регулярка, а глаз радует.

Answer (score 2):

Регулярка такая:

```
$text = "videoUpdate(2147383355,1363,1)";
preg_match("/\(([0-9]+),/", $text, $matches);
$result = preg_replace('/(.*)./', $matches[1], $text);
echo $result;
```

[Sandbox для теста](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/506af6e12a5daed951b10a6a5e965c0b53d899fb)

Comment: Спасибо, но первый ваш вариант был проще.

Comment: @gm-111, так это тот же самый. Только с заменой. Для первого варианта стоит только написать `echo $matches[1];` в конце :)